# ListFeatureClasses() glitch with SDE

Tags: python, gis, arcgis, arcpy

I'm running ListFeatureClasses() on every Feature Dataset in my SDE using arcpy - the line goes something like this:

```
FDS = arcpy.ListFeatureDatasets()
for FD in FDS: 
  arcpy.env.workspace = FD
  print arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
```

But for some of the feature datasets that I know (and can load data from), nothing is returned.  Has anyone ever gotten this issue?

Comment: Yes I'm dealing with that right now. For some reason ListFeatureClasses works on some SDE connections but not others. Its also not consistent for every machine. Got it to work on mine but not another machine.

Comment: The problem seems somehow related to having a feature class with the same name as the dataset that contains it. arcpy.da.Walk works very slightly better, by at least returning that one feature class, but ultimately I think we're stuck with a broken API.

Comment: dogtato - Thanks, I will definitely check out arcpy.da.Walk, I did not know it existed.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:**

Set the workspace before the loop:

`env.workspace = r"/path/to/geodatabase"`

Set the feature dataset list:

`datasets = arcpy.ListDatasets("*", "FeatureClass")`

Set a list to contain the feature datasets:

`fds = [fc for fc in datasets]`

Loop through the feature datasets grabbing their feature classes:

`for fd in fds:
    fc = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses("*", "ALL", fd)
    print "{}: {}".format(fd, fc)`

---

**Full snippet:**

```
from arcpy import env
import arcpy

env.workspace = r"path/to/geodatabase"

datasets = arcpy.ListDatasets("*", "FeatureClass")

fds = [fc for fc in datasets]

for fd in fds:
    fc = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses("*", "ALL", fd)
    print "{}: {}".format(fd, fc)`
```

[ListFeatureClasses (arcpy)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/ListFeatureClasses/03q300000023000000/)